# Controller Controls?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

My PS3 controller will not set up it's controls. I've gone to options, then controls, then selected my controller, but I can't set the controls, rendering my controller useless. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PS3 Controller does NOT work on Windows machines, it is not recognized like a X-Box Controller. But there is a tool called [MotioninJoy](http://motioninjoy.en.uptodown.com/) which is basically a driver for your PS3 controller. The installation is a bit complicated, but i use it for almost 3 years now and it is working completely fine.

Comment: there are also little script files to simulate the supported Xbox360 Controller over the PS3 layout ;D

Comment: @GEnGEr Okay, I did not know that, but thanks for the information. :)

Comment: Last I checked, Sony doesn't make a Windows driver for Dualshock 3 controllers... although I've heard they do for Dualshock 4 controllers.  Even then, the Dualshock 4 isn't XInput compatible without a program named DS4Tools.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think BOI:R supports PS3 controllers perhaps try a Xbox360 one they should work straight up.